# Error en las columnas de Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

estoy realizando un proyecto y tengo este error cuando quiero recuperar los datos de una tabla.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'El nombre de columna 'PersonalIdPersonal' no es válido.
El nombre de columna 'PersonalIdPersonal' no es válido.'

La cuestion es que no tengo ninguna columna con ese nombre, la ruta correcta seria Personal.IdPersonal, aca les dejo las clases que utilizo y el modelo de la base de datos, no puedo encontrar cual es el error.

Esta es la clase que utilizo para recuperar los datos del DBContext

```
[Table("HUM_Personal")]
public class Personal
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPersonal { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public string Dni { get; set; }
    public string EstadoCivil { get; set; }
    public bool IsActivo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaEgreso { get; set; }
    public int IdTipoPersona { get; set; }

    public List<IngresosPersonal> IngresosPersonal { get; set; }

}
```

Esta es la tabla de SqlServer

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [IdPersonal]
  ,[Nombre]
  ,[Apellido]
  ,[Sexo]
  ,[FechaIngreso]
  ,[FechaNacimiento]
  ,[Dni]
  ,[EstadoCivil]
  ,[FechaEgreso]
  ,[IdTipoPersona]
  ,[IsActivo]
FROM [HUM_Personal]
```

Y esta es la consulta que realuizo

```
List<Personal> lstPersonal = _context.Personal.Where(x => x.IsActivo == true).Include(x => x.IngresosPersonal).ToList();
```

Comment: Hola prueba ponerle la anotación [Column("IdPersonal")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code First crea una foreign key (FK) en la base de datos usando el patrón `[Nombre de la propiedad de navegación]_[Primary Key de la clase relacionada]`.

En este caso `Personal` unido con `IdPersonal` de ahí que trate de buscar `PersonalIdPersonal`.

Probablemente, te esté pasando porque has configurado una propiedad de navegación a la clase Personal pero no le has definido el IdPersonal para que la propiedad de navegación lo utilice.

Seguramente que te falte desde la tabla donde tienes el `include` que sería `IngresosPersonal` añadir un atributo similar a la siguiente `[ForeignKey("IdPersonal")]` encima de la propiedad que tiene la relación.

Por ejemplo si tuvieras en **IngresosPersonal**:

```
//Esta clave es la que utilizará el sistema para "interconectar" las tablas
public int IdPersonal { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("IdPersonal")]
public Personal Personal { get; set; }
```

De esta manera le estás indicando que Id es su FK, si no irá a buscar la que monta el sistema con el patrón de manera automática.

1. La propiedad `int IdPersonal` en la clase IngresosPersonal indica que es tipo numérico y será el registro de la base de datos.
2. La propiedad `Personal Personal` indica una propiedad de navegación y
   relaciona un modelo con otro. A nivel lógico pero digamos que "no
   sabe" de qué manera.
3. El atributo `ForeignKey` indica que propiedad de la clase (o campo de
   base de datos) tiene el campo con el que "físicamente" se harán las
   comprobaciones para realizar los "joins" y unirlas adecuadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo tienes otra entidad llamada IngresosPersonal.
Asegurate que ella tenga los campos:

```
public int PersonalId {get;set;}
public int Personal Personal {get;set;}
```